# What does [[Element].Element] mean in Swift's == operator overload?

Tags: swift

Swift's Array type implements Equatable protocol in a way that == and != operators are overloaded:

```
extension Array : Equatable where Element : Equatable {

    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - lhs: An array to compare.
    ///   - rhs: Another array to compare.
    public static func == (lhs: [[Element].Element], rhs: [[Element].Element]) -> Bool

    public static func != (lhs: [[Element].Element], rhs: [[Element].Element]) -> Bool
}
```

I've got three questions:

1. What is `[[Element].Element]`?
2. How to read that?
3. Why I cannot use that construct in my Swift code?

So far my reasoning is:

1. `[Element]` is a type definition, i.e. an array of types denoted by
   `Element` (`Element` is a placeholder type name).
2. Based on 1, next I reckon outermost brackets denote another array, BUT...
3. I can't figure out what `[Element].Element` means as `.Element` is puzzling for me.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile, where did you get that from? That's [not from the official Swift source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/dfed2796ae2501f7050bb922e6d6d53936e6cc67/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift#L1587) of `Array`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor: Actually, if you select the “==” in `if array1 == array2` and choose "Navigate -> Jump to Definition” in Xcode (10.1) then you'll see exactly the above definition. – Probably an artefact of the generated interface.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Jump to definition on Array type in Xcode and then look up Equatable. That's a real bummer that Xcode could not show the interface generated properly from the code you've linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, `TypeA.TypeB` can denote a nested type or type alias `TypeB`
inside `TypeA`, or an associated type `TypeB` of a protocol `TypeA`.

`Array` conforms to `Sequence`, and that has an `associatedtype Element`
for the type of the elements returned from its iterator. For arrays
that is equal to the array's element type. So for any type `T`:

```
Array<T>.Element == T
```

and consequently,

```
[Array<T>.Element] == [T]
```

Example:

```
print(type(of: [Array<Int>.Element].self))
// Array<Int>.Type
```

However, using the bracket notation for the inner array is not accepted
by the compiler:

```
print(type(of: [[Int].Element].self))
// Expected member name or constructor call after type name
```

Now back to your question: The actual definition of that `==` operator is

```
extension Array : Equatable where Element : Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: Array<Element>, rhs: Array<Element>) -> Bool {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The “generated interface” is, as you noticed:

```
extension Array : Equatable where Element : Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: [[Element].Element], rhs: [[Element].Element]) -> Bool
}
```

So apparently, the “interface generator” interprets the `Element` 
in `lhs: Array<Element>` not as the placeholder type, but as the associated
`Element` type of the `Sequence` protocol, i.e. the types of the operands
are

```
Array<Array<Element>.Element>
```

which – as shown above – is just `[Element]`. But then the interface
is emitted using the bracket notation

```
[[Element].Element]
```

which *should* be the same, but is not accepted by the compiler.

Comment: thank you for a very insightful answer. Following simple logic, since `Array<T>.Element == T` is a tautology, so when array literal is applied, the end result is equivalent to `Array<Element>`. I've accepted the answer. Many thanks for your detailed answer.